# How to make all input fields (with 100+ input fields existed already) in single form as "required"?

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, input

As title says.

I have a simple form with around 100 input fields, and I believe there should be an alternative 'shortcut' approach to simply typing out all 100 fields.

Is there a way to generate forms of this size using either PHP or Javscript?

Edit: sorry guys. Let me make this a bit clearer. I have a project regarding transforming a 10 pages long survey into a web form. As a result, I end up having a form with around 100 input fields. I wish to make them all "required" by using jQuery, php or javascript without changing all element on by one (as putting the "required" into all tags). Wish this clear some doubts.

Edit 2: I use jotform to generate this form. So I have the form in hand already. So I AM NOT ASKING HOW TO GENERATE, but how to alter this. Thanks.

Comment: How do you make a checkbox "required"?

Comment: dudes... the issue is I have 100+ inputs.... @RMcLeod

Comment: As at least use need to check one. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Bob, you should start use google to research before you ask, there is plenty number of tutorials on how to do this, If you are new to php/html go ahead and look at http://www.w3schools.com/ there is a lot of information that you could use, if you are not so new pick a framework CodeIgniter, Yii... and stick with it until you make a project or something.

Comment: Use a formchecker? http://mootools.floor.ch/en/demos/formcheck/

Comment: Use jquery form plugin if u r using jquery

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

You do this in two parts: The client side, and the server side.

### The Client Side

This is **purely** to make the UI easier to use, because all data must be validated on the server as well. But making UIs easier to use is important.

Here's how you do this:

1. You hook the `submit` event of the form.
2. You loop through the form's elements (the [`elements` collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) on the form) and check that they have a non-blank `value` (for `input type="text"` and `textarea`) or, in the case of radio buttons, that at least one of the ones sharing the same `name` has a `checked` attribute that's `true`. (You've also said that you have groups of checkboxes where you need at least one to be checked, so that would be similar to the radio button stuff, although you have to group them differently, perhaps using the same CSS class, which is available on each `input` as `className`.)
3. If you have any field that you don't feel is adequately filled in, you return `false` from the event handler for `submit`. Ideally you also show the user very clear instructions about what's missing.

There are about fifteen thousand "form validation" plug-ins to help you with this. HTML5 also has some form validation via markup now, but support isn't quite at the level you can rely on it yet.

### The Server Side

When you receive the form, you must re-validate that all of the required information is present, because client-side validation can be circumvented. Naturally how you do this depends on the content of the form, but the variables will be available via `$_POST` (if your form's `method="POST"`) or `$_GET` (if it's `method="GET"`). If the form will involve changing anything, naturally you'd use `POST` for that.

Comment: Thanks so much. I don't even know I could loop through all elements of a form. Will google about this.

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished with a little help of HTML5 for now. Try:

```
<input type="text" required="required" name="name" maxlength="5/>
<textarea required="required ... ></textarea>
```

etc...

Then you have to check if fields are really empty using PHP after form is submitted:

```
if(empty($_POST['name']))
    $messages[] = 'Please provide a name';
```

So forcing user to put data is a combination of HTML and PHP code. You can also use JavaScript, eq. for alerting if fields are still empty and user is trying to submit a form.

EDIT:

I see you've edited the post. You need to write your own control which could generate inputs, textareas, selects... Eg:

```
public static function addControl($type, $name, $options, $required = false, $howMuch = 1) 
{
    if($required)
        $required = 'required="required"';

    $name = 'name="'.$name.'"';

    $control = '';
    $controls = '';

    switch($type)
    {
        case 'input':
            $options = 'value="'.$options.'";
            $control = '<input type="text" '.$name.' '.$required.' '.$options.' />
        break;
        case ...:
    }
    if($howMuch > 1)
    {
        for($i = 1; $i < $howMuch; ++$i)
        {
            $controls .= $control;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        $controls = $control;
    }

self::$controls[] = $controls;
}
```

At the end of script method that shows all combined html code...

Comment: Thanks! I will try to use this method in looping through all my elements.